# Regular expression modelstate is false

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I've created the following regex:

```
(^[%a-zA-Z][\w\-.]+)( [\w\-.]+|[\w\-.]+)([%A-Za-z.]$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

strings that should be allowed e.g.

```
test (working)
test test (working)
%test (working)
test% (working)
%test% (working)
% (not working)
```

I tried the following to make % only work:

```
(%|(^[%a-zA-Z][\w\-.]+)( [\w\-.]+|[\w\-.]+)([%A-Za-z.]$))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

the defined pattern works fine with https://www.debuggex.com, but fails in my application, where the model looks like:

```
[Display(Name = "Publisher")]
[RegularExpression(@"(%|(^[%a-zA-Z][\w\-.]+)( [\w\-.]+|[\w\-.]+)([%A-Za-z.]$))", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Expression!")]    
public string SoftwarePublisher { get; set; }
```

any advice would be helpful. thanks in advance

Comment: +1 for the effort. What does it mean 'fails'? You got any exception or simply regex doesn't match things it should?

Comment: the added or statement (%| at the beginning of the regex makes %test and %test% fail.

Comment: so you want this regex to allow all of these: `test, test test, %test, test%, %test%, %` right?

Comment: yeah, thats what i wanna do - what am I missing?

Comment: apparently I have manager to write my own pattern which matches them all, posted an answer give it a try and leave feedback please : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern should be bit better than yours give it a try as it works for me:

**PATTERN**

```
(^|%)((\w+\s?)+)([^\s]$|%)|%
```

**INPUT**

```
case 1:    test
case 2:    test
case 3:    %test
case 4:    test%
case 5:    %test%
case 6:    %
```

**OUTPUT**

```
case 1:    matches
case 2:    matches
case 3:    matches
case 4:    matches
case 5:    matches
case 6:    matches
```

Hope it will work for you or at least give you some hint. If you will test it on some website use all strings separately as I'm using `^` and `$`.

Comment: many many thanks. looks pretty close, but the string should not be allowed to end with a space like "test "

Comment: this is an awesome solution - thx for the input. looks like regex can be shortened simple, if you know how :)

Comment: @pavemann that's true but usually they are that complicated so even if you know how it's not that easy to do ; ) Anyway glad it works for you : )

Answer (score 0):

The expression you are using will simply test negative for all string less then 4 characters. 2 for group 1, 1 (of 2) for group 2, and 1 for group 3.

You can check this to test with 'tes' which will fail, and '%%%%' which will pass (even if you take % out of you regex).

If you want help with the regex let us know what you are trying to achieve. In any case, writing down what you want your regex to do in human readable language first is advisable.

For instance:

Any string that:

- starts with 3 letters
- an optional '_'
- etc.

Comment: what I'm trying to achieve is:
- string can start with a % sign or a character
- string can also end with a % sign or a character
- string can contain spaces, but "% %" e.g. should not be allowed

that's it so far - hope this looks human readable now :)